# Unknown property attribute 'class' after Realm-Swift CocoaPod import

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, realm

I'm new to Xcode and Swift. Today I started a blank Tabbed Application with swift called "Test". I can build the blank project but as soon as I try to add Realm via CocoaPod it doesn't build anymore.

```
Error: Unknown property attribute 'class'
File: Test/Pods/Realm/Realm/RLMSyncSession.mm:73:12:
CocoaPod version: 1.2.0
Xcode version: Version 7.3.1 
Realm: 2.4.3
```

I did the pod init/update/install
PodFile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Test' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Test
  pod 'RealmSwift'

  target 'TestTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

After the install I opened the "Test.xcworkspace" file and tried to build the project but it fails. How to fix that?

Comment: Did you used pod setup ?

Comment: I forgot to mention, yes I did that.

Comment: @Murloc was it wrong to do the pod setup? If yes how to undo?

Comment: it was just to know how you set up Cocoapods with your Project. Can you try with the last version of Xcode ? 8.2.1 if I'm not wrong. Try to always keep your IDE updated.

Comment: Actually I thought that I have the latest version. But apparently not, so im downloading the latest version(8.2.1) from the App Store. I think that will fix the problem, thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is working. Feel free to post the solution as an answer and I will mark it as solved.

Comment: I have answered the question after the investigations done in the comments.

Comment: happens with xcode 13.3 as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue came from an outdated version of Xcode.

This causes the OP to not achieve his build and Cocoapods setup after adding Realm to his project.

After updated it to the last version (8.2.1 I suppose), as recommended in the comment, the pod mechanism worked and the build could finally be achieved.

Comment: Thank you. It's is working after updating to the newest Xcode version(8.2.1).

Answer (score 0):

just make your
iOS Development Target up to 15.0 and above,
Pods 15.0 and above